# bulk delete from redis

Tags: php, redis

Deleting cached values in bulk using hash taking a lot of time.

4000 keys in 1 hr.

Let me know how to do it effectively.

Note: I'm using pattern matching to find job ids that are unique in nature and simultaneously deleting it.

Comment: If you want an answer, you should add more details to your question. What is  _deleting using hash_ and  _pattern matching to find job_. Add some code.

Comment: I believe anybody with redis knowledge would understand what is hash and pattern matching here.
But needed i will explain more about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Anuj Mittal said you should add more details about your code.
However, to do a many redis operations you can use [pipeline](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) . On the other hand, the performance is too bad in your case. Redis can execute operations more than you mentioned. Based on documentation [here](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) :

```
$ redis-benchmark -t set,lpush -n 100000 -q
SET: 74239.05 requests per second
LPUSH: 79239.30 requests per second
```